# Как реализовать трение у Rigidbody2D с видом сверху

Tags: c#, unity3d, физика

Насколько я понял, в Rigidbody2D доступно трение при соприкосновении объектов, что нужно в основном для платформеров и т.п. с видом с боку. Если же игра с видом сверху, то трение должно замедлять все движущиеся объекты (так как концептуально они все движутся по какой-либо поверхности, которой технически нет в игре).

Идея 1: прикладывать силу F = -(единичный вектор скорости) * коэффициент.

```cs
Vector3 velocity_vector = rigidbody_object.velocity.normalized;
rigidbody_object.AddForce(-velocity_vector * Time.deltaTime * 100.0f);
// Кстати, надо умножать на deltatime или deltatime^2?
// По сути ускорение - м/c^2. Значит квадрат должен быть?
```

Однако в силу дискретности, вместо остановки объект начинает совершать "микроколебания". Это особенно заметно при больших значения коэффициента. Можно исправить костыльными способами, но мне это не нравиться.

Так вот, есть ли всё-таки такое трение в виде стандартной функции/другое в Rigidbody2D? Или как реализовать это самому? +мне ещё нужно трение вращения.

Comment: `Time.deltaTime` разумно использовать в `Update()`. В `FixedUpdate()` **необходимо** использовать `Time.fixedDeltaTime`. Если силу Вы прикладываете в `FixedUpdate`, то попробуйте использовать корректную дельту времени. Если в `Update` - то перенесите в `FixedUpdate` с правкой дельты. Если применение силы не связано ни тем, ни с другим методом, тогда откажитесь от `deltaTime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У rigidbody2D есть параметр Linear Drag, который определяет скорость замедления, а для вращения этот параметр называется Angular Drag, они не имеют какого-то физ. смысла, значения подбираются наугад)